# A/B testing with Meteor

Tags: meteor

What's a simple recipe to do A/B testing using Meteor?

In other words, in a Meteor environment, if I want to keep track of 2-5 versions of each view template without getting lost, is there a package or a de facto setup that's meant for this?

Comment: I wrote this tutorial, on split testing with meteor.js. Hopefully, it'll help you: https://themeteorchef.com/tutorials/split-testing-with-meteor

Answer (score 2):

if you are using google analytics and content experiments, you could use this:
https://github.com/reywood/meteor-iron-router-ga/

or implement client side [content experiments](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1745147) code yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The only A/B testing package available on Atmosphere is [manuel:abtest](https://atmospherejs.com/manuel/abtest), which hasn't received any updates since January 2015 and either works very well, or hasn't been used much (it has no functionality issues raised by the community).

Answer (score -1):

This is one solution I thought looked pretty interesting:
https://github.com/krzysu/meteor-ab-test

It's written in coffeescript, but the basic idea is that there is a ABTests handlebars helper that manages switching out the templates and measuring results.

Comment: That package hasn't been effectively maintained since 2013 and [no longer works](https://github.com/krzysu/meteor-ab-test/issues/1).

Comment: Got an update from the author to the issue linked in my comment above: "[N]o, this repo is not maintained and was only proof of concept long time ago. I will remove it to avoid confusion."